# How to compare two string variables

Tags: powershell

I am trying to compare a list of managed computers with details in a text file and writes to a variable if it finds a matching string.I am running the below program to compare , however not getting desired output. Can someone help to identify the error

```
$a = Get-content -path C:\temp\remove.txt

$agents = $Admin.GetAllAgentManagedComputers()

FOREACH ($agent in $agents)
{
    IF ($agent.DisplayName -match $a)
    {
        $NDList.Add($agent)
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't said what you expected output is, or the error you have referred to. This doesn't give people much to go on, try adding more detail to your question.

Howver, a couple of things that may help. try printing the values the you are comparing, it might give you a hint as why they don't match.

It's also worth pointing out that the match operator is a regex match so might not be what you want - maybe try the like operator - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the text file contains the exact `DisplayName` values, use the `-contains` operator:

```
if($a -contains $agent.DisplayName){
   # add to list
}
```

... or its complementary, the `-in` operator:

```
if($agent.DisplayName -in $a){
   # add to list
}
```

For more information, I'd suggest reading the [`about_Comparison_Operators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators#containment-operators) help file